# *ngIf not updating after Object is filled

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ng-if

I have a simple list page in which i declare a pokemons variable that gets filled through an API:

```js
export class ListPage implements OnInit { 
public pokemons: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public pokemonProvider: PokemonProviderService, public parametersProvider: ParameterProviderService) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
      this.counter = 1;
      this.pokemonProvider.getPokemons(this.counter).subscribe(result => this.pokemons = result);
      this.counter++;
  }
}
```

in my view i then have an ngFor, that loops through those pokemon and shows each one.

```html
<div *ngIf="pokemons">
<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons.results" (click)="showDetails(pokemon)">
      <!--<ion-icon [name]="item.icon" slot="start"></ion-icon>-->
      <!--<button ion-button ></button>-->
      <h3> {{pokemon.name}} </h3>

    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
            loadingSpinner="bubbles"
            loadingText="Loading more data...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
  <!--
    <div *ngIf="selectedItem" padding>
      You navigated here from <b>{{selectedItem.title }}</b>
    </div>
  -->
</ion-content>
</div>
```

however the ngIf never refreshes and always shows a white page. Even though 'pokemons' gets filled.

Comment: `this.pokemons = result;);` → remove the first semicolon

Comment: Do you have any console errors ?

Comment: @trichetriche i have done in my actual code, this was just a copying error

Comment: @trichetriche none at all

Comment: Check what getPokemons is returning. Right now you're expecting it has an attribute "results" that is an array of Pokemon. I'm guessing that's not right.

Comment: @WilliamHampshire when i remove the ngif entirely the program works exactly as expected. However then there are errors saying pokemons is undefined (because it returns the pokemons asyn)

Comment: Then all you have to do is make the *ngIf="pokemons.results"

Comment: @WilliamHampshire then i get the same error saying "cannot read property results of undefined"

Comment: @Roykovic "then i get the same error" didn't you say "none at all" when someone asked what error you're getting?

Comment: @WilliamHampshire i don't. by "the same error" i was referring to the error i got when i completely removed the ngif

Comment: All you have to do is add this.pokemons = {}; to your ngOnInit

Comment: @WilliamHampshire then the errors are gone, but the ngif still wont reload and only shows a white screen.

Comment: @Roykovic Your code makes no sense. You are only trying to getPokemons of index equal to 1. Make sure that this call returns non null value. Console log the returned value from subscription and check if it's what you expect. If it's returning null value, you know why -> debug pokemonProvider. The index++ does nothing to your call (there is no loop here). Also make sure that your getPokemons method return anything.

Comment: @qUest the index is indeed in a weird place, but does what it should do (it is an offset for the infinite scroll, so when you reach the bottom it knows to add the second page from the pokemon api). When i console log the pokemons in the subscribe it returns what i expect. And as said, when i completely remove the ngif the ngfor works and the pokemon list is shown. However the console shows "cannot read property results of undefined" because pokemons gets filled async and for that reason is undefined in the beginning.

Comment: @Roykovic Alright, I am not sure how Ionic renders the view. I would try to wrap ion-list or even items with ngIf to see if it changes anything - although it should work at the moment. Live example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping ion-content with div causes view to not render.
Below is a live working example. Try to use *ngIf on ion-content instead.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vndmrx

Comment: can't beleive it was that simple. Works like a charm, thank you!